# Installing VS Code for Linux: Failed to Retrieve App Info

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, chromebook

I'm trying to install VS Code on my Chromebook and have turned on Linux, however when trying to install the VS Code files I get a 'Failed to Retrieve App Info' error message. How do I solve this and go about fully installing VS Code? Haven't found any other information online to help me solve this. Thanks in advance

Edit: also cannot access the Linux terminal
[Linux terminal screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqEEO.png)

Comment: Did you download the installer from [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/download)?

Comment: Yes, .deb Ubuntu

Comment: What is your CPU?
If you don't know that, use [this extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/get-cpu-info/lhemjfjfepodolblmgmonhmbfkaaapam?hl=en&authuser=0) to check modelName.

Comment: Intel(R) Celeron(R) CPU N3060 @ 1.60GHz (2 threads, 2.48GHz)

Comment: Are your steps the same as [this video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1L9T4UknkFBbyo6Mfa0M-1Rx41f3l5qgq/view?usp=drive_link) ?

Comment: Yes, exactly that, could it be a lack of storage space?

Comment: I cannot access the terminal either (see screenshot in post)

Comment: After removing Linux, please reinstall it.

Comment: I've done that and the same thing happened

Comment: Can you capture the error message?
If I were you, I would restore the Chromebook to its factory settings.